# Copy from std::deque to thrust device_vector

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, thrust, stddeque

I'm trying to make a sample code where I copy from a `std::deque` to a `thrust::device_vector` but the compiler warns `calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed` (I tried to copy-paste the entire error here but it is beyond the limit of characters in questions). I can post more details if needed.

The code compiles successfully, but I'm really annoyed by these errors as they do not happen with other stl containers as `std::list` and `std::vector`.
I want to know why they are happening and how do I fix these warning.

Here is the `nvcc --version` result:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

Here is my sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

const uint size = 100;

__global__
void hello (int *a) {
  a[threadIdx.x] += threadIdx.x;
}

int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
  std::deque<int> a(size);
  std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);

  thrust::device_vector<int> a_cuda(a.begin(), a.end());

  dim3 dimBlock(size, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);
  hello<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&a_cuda[0]));

  thrust::copy(a_cuda.begin(), a_cuda.end(), a.begin());

  for (const int i : a) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is the command I'm using to compile:

```
nvcc file.cu -std=c++11 -O3 -o hello
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's your question, and what would you like us to do about?

Comment: As I said, I'm annoyed with the error output and I want to know why this is happening / how to fix it (just edited to add these two last parts, thanks for pointing it out)

Comment: Well, you only said you were annoyed. You didn't actually ask any sort of question. I think you should be posting this as a bug report to the thrust developers, not asking about it here. It is obvious that there is something broken in the thrust copy constructor which is emitting code when it probably shouldn't (it also does it with thrust::host_vector copy construction with a std::deque as the source)

Comment: I thought it was a problem on my code or even a limitation when copying using deques. I will keep it open to see if someone knows what is happening and I will file a bug report on thrust. Thanks

Comment: As a workaround, if you copy to a `std::vector` first, you can go from there